# I'm developing on the Test network. Are there any "rules" or communication methods I should adopt?

Tags: protocol, attack, testnet, testing, c#

I'm testing a C# port of the client on the Test network and need to test for a variety of conditions.

- Should I communicate to others regarding my actions on the network?  If so, what method of communication should I use?
- Is there any expected behavior I should / should not do on the Test network such as mine with FPGA or ASIC?
- Suppose I want to co-operatively test the resilience and response to invalid blocks and network attacks, should I do it on the test network?  Where would I coordinate this?

Answer (score 4):

Testnet code has been modified to lessen the impact of fluctuations of hashing power mining against testnet:

- http://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/686

If you wish to test against your own testnet, or think you might interfere with others needlessly, then [Testnet-In-A-Box](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/testnet-in-a-box/) is for you.

Now this doesn't mean you shouldn't use Testnet -- especially if you find something you think might be disruptive to bitcoin.  Feel free to verify your suspicions on Testnet even if it slams it hard.  That's why it exists.

Comment: As far as communications, the #bitcoin-dev IRC channel (Freenode) is where a lot of development banter occurs.